# How do I allow web browsers to remember form fields that are not sent in a standard way?

Tags: javascript, forms

The following code almost works flawlessly.

```
function post_form() {
    http=new XMLHttpRequest();

    http.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (http.readyState==4 && http.status==200) some_div.innerHTML=http.responseText;
    };

    http.open("POST", some_action_url, false);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.send(my_form_query(some_form_element));
}
```

Almost, except, when the client reloads the page they have to re-enter their name again because the browser isn't auto completing form fields.

So my question is, how do I allow web browsers to remember form fields that are not sent in a standard way?

Comment: Can you show us your form code please?

Answer (score 0):

It's a litle complex. You can send the from fields to server to save as a 'draft' when the form fields changed.

eg:

```
setInterval(autoSave, 1000);
function autoSave() {
    if form is changed {
        use ajax to post form fields to server to save as a draft
    }
}
```

when user reloads the page, fill the form fields with your saved draft.